# Is it possible to replace the .Machine$double.eps value in R globally, or set the tol value of the solve.default globally?

Tags: r

I know this could be a bit risky - but when I was recently running a locally weighted linear regression model, quite a few local linear models result in singular matrix that cannot be inverted because the reciprocal conditional number is way smaller than the default .Machine$double.eps value.

I tried to manually set .Machine$double.eps to a very small number (like 1e-50), but running the locally weighted regression will ignore this manually set value. When I debug into the solve.default() function, I saw every time I can reset the tol parameter to a small number, but when it repeats again, the tol will return to the default .Machine$double.eps value, and the inversion will report an error.

Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Dan

Comment: You can't really "change" that value with software. It's a machine defined constant. From the documentation: the smallest positive floating-point number x such that 1 + x != 1. It equals double.base ^ ulp.digits if either double.base is 2 or double.rounding is 0; otherwise, it is (double.base ^ double.ulp.digits) / 2. Normally 2.220446e-16.

Comment: Thank you, Dason. In that case, is there any way to change the "tol" parameter for the solve.default() function - it uses the .Machine$double.eps as the default value. Much appreciated.

Comment: Of course you can do something like `solve(a, b, tol = 1e-50)`. If the model function you are using doesn't have a way to pass the `tol` parameter, you could even use `trace` to modify the default. But that's unlikely to solve your problems. If a matrix is basically singular, it's basically singular. The default tolerance is set this way to protect you.

Comment: You should give details on how you are doing your local linear fits.  It may be that there's a different way to do that which won't care about singularity (but may lose smoothness).

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, Roland and user2554330. Roland is right, I was toying around the estimation to see if anything can be produced so that I can further delve into the data and find out potential issues that might exist in the data. I would appreciate it if you can point to how to modify the default using trace. For user 2554330, my local linear fit is very similar to the LOWESS procedure - I am using only a portion of the data within a neighborhood and estimate the linear regression using only this portion. It works for some portions, but not all. Please point me to the different ways.